# iphone and ipad development

Tags: iphone, ipad

Can anyone explain how to start with iPhone and iPad development?
Dont you have to pay? or is it just pay when you release?

I dont see where to get the iPad SDK or anything.

I already have XCode 3.2.1 on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 7):

You have to pay $99 to test your app on a real device.  You can develop for iPhone and iPad with the simulator for free though. Go to the [Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action) site and login to download the iPhone SDK 3.2 beta. There you will find necessary iPad resources.

Comment: @coney - so I dont have to pay to start?

Comment: No. Only if you want to test on your physical device or submit to the store.

Comment: Right, you don't need to pay to get started. Now, iPad is in beta, and generally you can't get the beta SDK w/o being a paid member. Apple's web site (usually) explains it better than someone could here. Did you gather info from apple?)

Answer (score 3):

I think coneybeare has this right. To summarize it:

- You don't need to be a paid member to get the SDK (to get started)
- but, iPad's SDK is in beta, so you do need to be a member (*for now*)

The important thing here is to get started, you need to learn the library (and maybe the language). There is no point in paying the $99 to become a member just because you want to work with the iPad specific libraries (which are in beta anyway).

You should get started by learning the basics of the OS's SDK and then, when ready, move to the iPad's SDK. It is likely that once apple releases the iPad, non-members will be able to get the iPad SDK like non-members can get the iPhone SDK.

You should check out these links (namely the first one):

- http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/develop.html#compare
- http://www.apple.com/ipad/sdk/

**What does being a paid member get you?**

- Access to **beta** SDKs (which include the iPad, for now)
- The ability to test on a device
- the ability to submit to apple for distribution

Answer (score 1):

You need to register yourself as a developer on http://developer.apple.com.

Registration costs $99/yr.

You can download the SDK and then release apps through the iTunes AppStore. This doesn't cost you anything.

Comment: @sheehan - so I dont have to pay to start developing?

Comment: No, you don't, unless you want to test on a real iPod or iPhone etc. (which is absolutely necessary since the simulator has tons more memory than the actually devices, and the clock speed is much faster etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I think, since the 3.2 SDK is still a beta, you can't download it unless you are a paying developer, so you can only start developing for iphone (not ipad) without paying